# rails adding a iframe from youtube in to a string

Tags: ruby-on-rails, iframe

Am trying to add a youtube embedment to a string(video.link) but it crashs my app am using redCloth to handle the html output. Not sure what to do with the passenger error, can anyone help?

error message:

```
ActionController::RoutingError (No route matches [GET] "/403.shtml"):
  vendor/bundle/ruby/1.8/gems/actionpack-3.2.11/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/debug_exceptions.rb:21:in `call'
  vendor/bundle/ruby/1.8/gems/actionpack-3.2.11/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/show_exceptions.rb:56:in `call'
  vendor/bundle/ruby/1.8/gems/railties-3.2.11/lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:32:in `call_app'
  vendor/bundle/ruby/1.8/gems/railties-3.2.11/lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:16:in `call'
  vendor/bundle/ruby/1.8/gems/activesupport-3.2.11/lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:22:in `tagged'
  vendor/bundle/ruby/1.8/gems/railties-3.2.11/lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:16:in `call'
  vendor/bundle/ruby/1.8/gems/actionpack-3.2.11/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/request_id.rb:22:in `call'
  vendor/bundle/ruby/1.8/gems/rack-1.4.5/lib/rack/methodoverride.rb:21:in `call'
  vendor/bundle/ruby/1.8/gems/rack-1.4.5/lib/rack/runtime.rb:17:in `call'
  vendor/bundle/ruby/1.8/gems/activesupport-3.2.11/lib/active_support/cache/strategy/local_cache.rb:72:in `call'
  vendor/bundle/ruby/1.8/gems/rack-1.4.5/lib/rack/lock.rb:15:in `call'
  vendor/bundle/ruby/1.8/gems/rack-cache-1.2/lib/rack/cache/context.rb:136:in `forward'
  vendor/bundle/ruby/1.8/gems/rack-cache-1.2/lib/rack/cache/context.rb:245:in `fetch'
  vendor/bundle/ruby/1.8/gems/rack-cache-1.2/lib/rack/cache/context.rb:185:in `lookup'
  vendor/bundle/ruby/1.8/gems/rack-cache-1.2/lib/rack/cache/context.rb:66:in `call!'
  vendor/bundle/ruby/1.8/gems/rack-cache-1.2/lib/rack/cache/context.rb:51:in `call'
  vendor/bundle/ruby/1.8/gems/railties-3.2.11/lib/rails/engine.rb:479:in `call'
  vendor/bundle/ruby/1.8/gems/railties-3.2.11/lib/rails/application.rb:223:in `call'
  vendor/bundle/ruby/1.8/gems/railties-3.2.11/lib/rails/railtie/configurable.rb:30:in `send'
  vendor/bundle/ruby/1.8/gems/railties-3.2.11/lib/rails/railtie/configurable.rb:30:in `method_missing'
  passenger (3.0.9) lib/phusion_passenger/rack/request_handler.rb:96:in `process_request'
  passenger (3.0.9) lib/phusion_passenger/abstract_request_handler.rb:513:in `accept_and_process_next_request'
  passenger (3.0.9) lib/phusion_passenger/abstract_request_handler.rb:274:in `main_loop'
  passenger (3.0.9) lib/phusion_passenger/rack/application_spawner.rb:205:in `start_request_handler'
  passenger (3.0.9) lib/phusion_passenger/rack/application_spawner.rb:170:in `send'
  passenger (3.0.9) lib/phusion_passenger/rack/application_spawner.rb:170:in `handle_spawn_application'
  passenger (3.0.9) lib/phusion_passenger/utils.rb:479:in `safe_fork'
  passenger (3.0.9) lib/phusion_passenger/rack/application_spawner.rb:165:in `handle_spawn_application'
  passenger (3.0.9) lib/phusion_passenger/abstract_server.rb:357:in `__send__'
  passenger (3.0.9) lib/phusion_passenger/abstract_server.rb:357:in `server_main_loop'
  passenger (3.0.9) lib/phusion_passenger/abstract_server.rb:206:in `start_synchronously'
  passenger (3.0.9) lib/phusion_passenger/abstract_server.rb:180:in `start'
  passenger (3.0.9) lib/phusion_passenger/rack/application_spawner.rb:128:in `start'
  passenger (3.0.9) lib/phusion_passenger/spawn_manager.rb:253:in `spawn_rack_application'
  passenger (3.0.9) lib/phusion_passenger/abstract_server_collection.rb:132:in `lookup_or_add'
  passenger (3.0.9) lib/phusion_passenger/spawn_manager.rb:246:in `spawn_rack_application'
  passenger (3.0.9) lib/phusion_passenger/abstract_server_collection.rb:82:in `synchronize'
  passenger (3.0.9) lib/phusion_passenger/abstract_server_collection.rb:79:in `synchronize'
  passenger (3.0.9) lib/phusion_passenger/spawn_manager.rb:244:in `spawn_rack_application'
  passenger (3.0.9) lib/phusion_passenger/spawn_manager.rb:137:in `spawn_application'
  passenger (3.0.9) lib/phusion_passenger/spawn_manager.rb:275:in `handle_spawn_application'
  passenger (3.0.9) lib/phusion_passenger/abstract_server.rb:357:in `__send__'
  passenger (3.0.9) lib/phusion_passenger/abstract_server.rb:357:in `server_main_loop'
  passenger (3.0.9) lib/phusion_passenger/abstract_server.rb:206:in `start_synchronously'
  passenger (3.0.9) helper-scripts/passenger-spawn-server:99
```

Form view:

```
<%= form_for(@video) do |f| %>
  <% if @video.errors.any? %>
    <div id="error_explanation">
      <h2><%= pluralize(@video.errors.count, "error") %> prohibited this video from being saved:</h2>

      <ul>
      <% @video.errors.full_messages.each do |msg| %>
        <li><%= msg %></li>
      <% end %>
      </ul>
    </div>
  <% end %>

  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :title %><br />
    <%= f.text_field :title %>
  </div>
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :link %><br />
    <%= f.text_field :link %>
  </div>



  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :body %><br />
    <%= f.text_area :body %>
  </div>


  <div class="actions">
    <%= f.submit %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

Show view:

```
<p id="notice"><%= notice %></p>

<p>
  <b>Title:</b>
  <%= @video.title %>
</p>

<p>
  <b>Body:</b>
  <%= @video.body %>
</p>


<div id="video"><%= raw RedCloth.new(@video.link).to_html %></div>


<%= link_to 'Edit', edit_video_path(@video) %> |
<%= link_to 'Back', videos_path %>
```

Answer (score 0):

I forgot to added :link to the attr_accessible

```
class Video < ActiveRecord::Base

  attr_accessible :body, :title, :link


end
```